# XWPFDocument - replacing text doesn't work

Tags: java

I want to replace tags with values in a docx document.
Here is a line of the document :

```
<Site_rattachement>, le <date_avenant>
```

I want to replace `<Site_rattachement>` and `<date_avenant>` by some value.

My code :

```
doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(docxFile));
for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
    List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
    if (runs != null) {
        for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
            String text = r.getText(0);
            replaceIfNeeded(r, text, my_value);
        }
    }
}
```

But first r.getText(0) gives me `<` instead of `<Site_rattachement>`.

Next occurence gives me `Site_rattachement`.

Next occurence gives me `>`.

Is there something wrong with my docx file?

Comment: You might want to check your encoding, maybe there are some zero-width space within the text?

Comment: How do I check encoding  with XWPFDocument ? (I am using ubuntu and the docx is opened with LibreOffice)